# Regular expression for items listed in plain english

Tags: java, regex

This is sort of a contrived example, but I'm trying to get at a general principle here.

Given phrases written in English using this list-like form:

```
I have a cat
I have a cat and a dog
I have a cat, a dog, and a guinea pig
I have a cat, a dog, a guinea pig, and a snake
```

Can I use a regular expression to get all of the items, regardless of how many there are?  Note that the items may contain multiple words.

Obviously if I have just one, then I can use `I have a (.+)`, and if there are exactly two, `I have a (.+) and a (.+)` works.

But things get more complicated if I want to match more than just one example.  If I want to extract the list items from the first two examples, I would think this would work: `I have a (.*)(?: and a (.*))?` And while this works on the first phrase, telling me I have a `cat` and `null`, for the second one it tells me I have a `cat and a dog` and `null`.  Things only get worse when I try to match phrases in even more forms.

Is there any way I can use regexes for this purpose?  It seems rather simple, and I don't understand why my regex that matches 2-item lists works, but the one that matches 1- or 2-item lists does not.

Comment: If you have a consistent format, _maybe_, but English as a whole is not a regular language. What _programming_ language are you using to test the expressions?

Comment: Yes, it always follows this format exactly as I described, with (first item) (middle items, delimited with comma and article) (final item with comma and the word "and" and article), with the middle and final items being optional.  Also, this is in Java.

Comment: isn't it better to split by colon?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a non-capturing group as a conditional delimiter (either a comma or end-of-line): 
`' a (.*?)(?:,|$)'`

Example in python:

```
import re
line = 'I have a cat, a dog, a guinea pig, and a snake'
mat = re.findall(r' a (.*?)(?:,|$)', line)
print mat # ['cat', 'dog', 'guinea pig', 'snake']
```

Comment: Not bad, but in Java at least, this doesn't work for the second example (`I have a cat and a dog`).  This seems to work, though: `" a (.*?)(?:,| and|$)"`  But finding them in a loop is definitely better than my approach of finding them all at once.

Answer (score 1):

I use regex splitting to do it. But this assumes sentence format exactly matching your input set:

```
>>> SPLIT_REGEX = r', |I have|and|, and'
>>> for sample in ('I have a cat', 'I have a cat and a dog', 'I have a cat, a dog, and a guinea pig', 'I have a cat, a dog, a guinea pig, and a snake'):
...     print [x.strip() for x in re.split(SPLIT_REGEX, sample) if x.strip()]
... 
['a cat']
['a cat', 'a dog']
['a cat', 'a dog', 'a guinea pig']
['a cat', 'a dog', 'a guinea pig', 'a snake']
```

Comment: This works fairly well, but it's giving me some zero-length matches (I am using Java, however).  Also it's keeping the `a`s, but using split is probably better than my approach.  I guess I was trying to match phrases in that form and extract the items at the same time, but it's probably best to do each independently.

Comment: @codebreaker I would strip the articles in a subsequent step. Especially since there's 'a'  and 'an' differences. Don't want to make the regex too complicated.

Comment: @codebreaker The zero-length matches were filtered out by the `if x.strip()` clause.

Comment: Oh, okay.  I didn't see the `if x.strip` clause.  That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to use the `\G` anchor with the `find` method:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)(?:,? and|,)|\bI have) an? ((?>[b-z]+|\Ba|a(?!nd\b))+(?> (?>[b-z]+|\Ba|a(?!nd\b))+)*)
```

or more simple:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)(?:,? and|,)|\bI have) an? ((?!and\b)[a-z]+(?> (?!and\b)[a-z]+)*)
```

The `\G` is the position in the string after the last match. The pattern has two entry points. The first match will use the second entry point: `\bI have`, and next matches, the first entry point that allows only contiguous results.

Note: `\G` means match the position after the last match but it match the start of the string too.  `(?!\A)` is here to avoid this case.

[online demo](http://regex101.com/r/pD3kC0/1)

[regex planet](http://fiddle.re/ra85u) *(click the Java button)*

Comment: That's quite a regex, and it works pretty well, but does it have any advantage over doing something like what @alfasin did?  That seems much simpler.

Comment: @codebreaker: Yes, since this pattern allows only contiguous matches, it ensures that the string format is as you want. This pattern can not match "a white rabbit" everywhere in a larger string for example. The sentence must begin with I have . This kind of pattern captures the elements you want and check the format at the same time.

Comment: @codebreaker: Note that you can improve it by testing that the last match is at the end of the string with a little trick.

Answer (score 1):

Provide one java implementiaon, using the positive lookahead regexp. See below:

```
String str0 = "I have a cat";
String str1 = "I have a cat and a dog";
String str2 = "I have a cat, a dog, and a guinea pig";
String str3 = "I have a cat, a dog, a guinea pig, and a snake";

String regexp = "(?m)\\ba\\s+.*?(?=(?:,|$|and))";

Pattern pMod = Pattern.compile(regexp);
Matcher mMod = pMod.matcher(str3);

while (mMod.find()) {
    System.out.println(mMod.group(0));
}
```

For str3, the output is:

```
a cat
a dog
a guinea pig
a snake
```

if the item could be 'a', 'an', or 'one' starting, then the regex could be `(?m)\\b(one|an|a)\\s+.*?(?=(?:,|$|and))`

`(?m)` means to enable the MULTILINE flag when doing the parsing.
In multiline mode the expressions ^ and $ match just after or just before, respectively, a line terminator or the end of the input sequence. By default these expressions only match at the beginning and the end of the entire input sequence.

Comment: What is the modifier `(?m)` for?

Comment: I have added the explanation in my answers. Thanks.

Comment: I know what the modifier is *for*. But why do you add it to the expression? All examples are single lines.

Comment: Hi, yes. In my code, the intput is single line, (therefore, the (?m) is not necessary), if the user gets the whole input from the file, it will be useful.Thanks.